# How to move a circle $e^{i \pi n}$ along the $\Re$ axis to form a sine wave?

Tags: complex-numbers

Is there a way to move the unit circle $e^{i \pi n}$ where $n \in \mathbb{R}$ along the real axis to form a sine wave?

I know I can just replace the $\Re$ part of the result with $n$ but is there a mathematical way of doing that?

Something like $ 2 n \pi + e^{ni/ \pi}$ (below) but an exact sine wave resembling $y=sin(\pi x)$? The wavelength of the graph below is 125.4...

[image]

Comment: Since you use both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\Re$ you should explain what they mean.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ are the real numbers and $\Re$ is the real component of complex numbers. They are the same thing really, I just picked up the subtle convention from what I've seen on stackoverflow.

Comment: @GEdgar: these are the well-known set of real numbers and real part functions, no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using complex numbers, a sine wave can be represented as

$$at+ib\sin t$$ where $a$ and $b$ are scaling factors. In terms of the complex exponential,

$$at+\frac b2(e^{it}-e^{-it}).$$

---

If you absolutely want to "move a circle", which I understand as "consider the trajectory of a point of a rotating circle the center of which moves horizontally" (?), you need to solve

$$x(t)+be^{it}=at+ib\sin t$$ which tells you the motion of the center,

$$x(t)=at-b\cos t.$$

Finally,

$$at-b\cos t+be^{it}$$ which does not seem any better than the very first expression.

---

Note that the expression

$$at+be^{it}$$ describes a trochoid, a special case of which is a cycloid.

Comment: Thank you Yves!

Comment: The cycloid led me to $cis$ which led me to $sin(x)=(e^{i x} - e^{-i x})/2i$ .